# What would be the benefit of folding and rerolling chapati dough?

Tags: indian-cuisine

I am a new person to cooking. My mom used to make chapathis, and I saw, that sometimes, she used to fold them up and rolled them out again in an attempt to make softer chapathis.

I just wanted to know, how does this work(if it does)?

And if it works, would rolling the dough into a strand and twisting it into a knot instead of into a disk over and over work as well? I tried this method once and it seemed to kind of work.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  It's not clear what your actual question is.  What are you trying to find out?  It will help if you can explain what you mean by "knotting", since you're using that word in a way that it's not usually used.  Ideally, share a photo.

Comment: I mean making a long tube of dough and knotting it on itself like it was a thread... The first part of my question was how does folding the rolled uncooked dough on itself in various shapes and rolling it supposed to make the final cooked version softer

Comment: Still struggling to understand, sorry. Am I understanding correctly that your mom sometimes rolls out the dough, folds it up and then rolls it out again? (As for the benefit of that I could make an educated guess.) Or something else? And for the second part, do you mean tube as in hollow at some point by rolling out the dough, then rolling it into a log-shaped form and making a knot in that? Or just a solid rope and then making a knot?

Comment: My bad, your first assumption is correct, and the tube is solid

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what your actual question is.   Please edit your question to make it clear what information you're asking for.

Comment: @NetiSasidhar I tried to rewrite your question based on the comment discussion. Could you please check if I understood your question correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways of adding layers to dough, but you will have to decide which one you prefer, or if it’s necessary.  Two common techniques for flatbreads:

- Oil the dough, then fold it in half, oil again, fold in the other direction, then possibly roll it out gently before cooking: https://kiss100.co.ke/lifestyle/2023-05-13-how-to-prepare-soft-layered-kenyan-chapatis/
- Oil the dough, roll it into a snake, flatten the snake, roll it into a cylinder (tucking the outside end in), flatten the cylinder with your hand then roll it out to the desired size: https://thefoodietakesflight.com/scallion-bing-chinese-flat-bread/

The example recipes were selected simply because they did a good job of explaining the technique and had reference pictures.  Although the second one added other fillings, you don’t need to for the lamination technique.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought it could be to layer the final chapatti. I've seen them both ways, single-layered & multiple. It seems to depend on the chef.

[image]

<sup>I was just eating lunch at my desk when I was reminded of this question.

Home made chicken nihari, tarka dahl, onion bhaji, mint sauce & basmati - just to make you hungry. The bread was bought though, mine isn't as good.</sup>